# PHP only shows errors and no output

Tags: php, output

I'm having a hard time trying to get PHP to be in a state where I can debug errors. After finally managing to output errors (instead of Internal Server Error), I noticed that I don't get any output from before the error. If I try to `var_dump` the variable that is causing the error, I get nothing - just the output from the error, saying the was an error on some line. As you can imagine, this makes debugging extremely hard if not impossible.

Is there any option in the `php.ini` or somewhere else where I can change that? If it helps anything, I noticed that the error-messages are just plain-text even though the `html_errors` option in specified (according to `phpinfo()`). I'm running PHP 5.4.30 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with Plesk. If you need additional information, I'll happily provide it :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to [install the xdebug extension](http://xdebug.org/docs/install). It produces "nice" looking error messages and var_dumps (+ a lot of other useful features for debugging)

Comment: *PHP doesn't only shows errors and no output* Your title is kinda confusing

Comment: @1nflktd: Thank's for the hint - don't know how I missed that when checking it before posting